# Invalid class "Graph" object: superclass "mMatrix" not defined (Seurat/R)

Tags: r, object, nearest-neighbor, seurat, harmony

I am using Seurat for my RNAseq analysis and have been using the same code for over a month now (without issues). FindNeighbors gives an error now (out of the blue) and I can't seem to fix it.
The data and code are the same as before.

```
all.integrated <- all.integrated %>%
  FindNeighbors(reduction = "harmony", dims = 1:30) %>%
  FindClusters(reduction = "harmony", resolution = 0.1) %>%
  RunUMAP(reduction = "harmony", dims=1:30)


> Computing nearest neighbor graph
> Computing SNN
> Error in validObject(.Object) : 
invalid class “Graph” object: superclass "mMatrix" not defined in 
the environment of the object's class
```

I've checked the class and it is a SeuratObject. The only thing that worked yesterday was deleting and re-installing R and R studio (restart R wouldn't help), but now it gives the same error. What to do?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Furthermore, subsetting also does not work and gives the following error:
Error in getClassDef(x@superClass, package = packageSlot(x))@virtual : 
  no applicable method for `@` applied to an object of class "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem just now. According to [this bug report](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/8021) in the Seurat Github page, it looks like the problem is coming from the new version of the Matrix package (1.6.2).

Downgrading to Matrix v1.6.1 resolved it for me:

```
remotes::install_version("Matrix", "1.6.1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately my R does not seem te accept this... Also gives an error:

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Matrix’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Matrix’
Warning: installation of package ‘/var/folders/7f/xpsl62cd4h12h1db2qybsxpm0000gn/T//RtmpVLBYgS/remotesd0b3733eae04/Matrix’ had non-zero exit status

Do you know why?

Comment: Not sure... you have to look at the error more specifically (at which point it gave an error). Maybe try restarting R, uninstalling Matrix and re-installing version 1.6.1

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately this wouldn't do :(

Comment: @MarieSN If compilation fails, there are usually other error messages above the last one. Take a look at them, maybe there's a missing dependency?

Comment: Many thanks all for your help! It has been fixed: it was a compilation issue which I have solved with gfortran installation.

Answer (score 0):

You must re-install **SeuratObject** <= 5.0.0 from sources after changing between **Matrix** < 1.6-2 and **Matrix** >= 1.6-2.

```r
install.packages("SeuratObject", type = "source")
```

**SeuratObject** 5.0.1 has `Imports: Matrix (>= 1.6-3)` so another option is simply to update **SeuratObject**.

Comment: many thanks for your comment! Unfortunately my R does not change Matrix package (gives error), with for example 
> remotes::install_version("Matrix", version = "1.6.1")

Comment: My suggestion was to re-install **SeuratObject**, not to re-install **Matrix**.

Comment: Many thanks all for your help! It has been fixed: it was a compilation issue which I have solved with gfortran installation.